# Why isn't the WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION being detected by the broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, raspberry-pi-zero

So this the first time I work with wifi-direct, I am trying to connect my android phone to a raspberry pi zero w over wifi-direct.
using this sample app on my android phone: https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo

I am able to get to the Connected state at the pi in the wpa_cli interface
and on the phone under the device name i see "connected" behind the progressDialog box that says "Connecting to 1e:67:58:4c:78:92" which should be dismissed after connecting but it isn't since WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION isn't being triggered after connecting.

my wpa_supplicant.conf:

> ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
> update_config=1
> country=LB
> ap_scan=1
> device_name=raspberry
> device_type=1-0050F204-1
> driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
> p2p_go_intent=7
> p2p_go_ht40=1
> p2p_listen_reg_class=81
> p2p_listen_channel=1
> p2p_oper_reg_class=81
> p2p_oper_channel=1

and have done the following:

on the Pi:

> $sudo wpa_supplicant -B -dd -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
>
> $sudo wpa_cli p2p-dev-wlan0
>
> p2p_group_add 
> OK
> <3>P2P-GROUP-STARTED p2p-wlan0-0 GO ssid="DIRECT-VC" freq=2412 passphrase="JrLfUAJf" go_dev_addr=5a:d3:65:e8:fc:e7 
> wps_pbc
> OK
> <3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND 1e:67:58:4c:78:92 p2p_dev_addr=1e:67:58:4c:78:92 pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='HUAWEI' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0 wfd_dev_info=0x00101c440032 new=1
> <3>P2P-PROV-DISC-PBC-REQ 1e:67:58:4c:78:92 p2p_dev_addr=1e:67:58:4c:78:92 pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='HUAWEI' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0

On the Phone:
I run the wifi direct sample app from google
and i can see the device with its info and when i click on connect i get stuck at connecting progressDialog and cant get passed that point to connected mode eventhough i see "connected" under device name.

the app seems to work fine between two phones but with a pi
this line in [WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java](https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo/blob/master/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java) doesn't get executed when a connection has been made with the pi

> } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))

however, when connection is lost after a timeout for example it gets triggered!

my question is what am i doing wrong here, why isn't the WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION being detected by the broadcast receiver?

**Note:** phone is running Android 7.1
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26

**edit:**

As Ben has pointed out in his answer below that I need to have a DHCP server running on the GO device (PI in my case), so I went ahead and installed and configured DHCP service on the pi by following the first section at this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md
but, I can no longer run sudo wpa_supplicant -B -dd -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf command successfully as it might be clashing with the dhcp conf? any idea how i can enable p2p while running DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
So as a part of GDPR (EU) implementation and similar things. 
From android 8 & onwards there will be a restriction on the way by which android devices receive broadcast on any event (ofcourse to hide few device specific infos/specs.)

Please have a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, however, after checking it I don't seem to be violating the new rules, and as I mentioned when running between two phones, a WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION is received and the app proceeds, while between the phone and the pi it it is not being caught, it only catches a disconnection action.

Answer (score 0):

Your Raspberry Pi is in the GO role and needs to act as a DHCP server. An Android device in the Client role will not broadcast `WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION` until it has received an IP address from the GO via DHCP.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54555774) for further details.

Comment: Thank you Ben, your answer makes a lot of sense, I am trying to test it but the issue is after I installed and configured dhcp on the pi by following the first section at this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md I can no longer run sudo wpa_supplicant -B -dd -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf command successfully as it might be clashing with the dhcp conf? any idea how i can enable p2p while running dhcp?